# How to put error message to out file in XSLT

Tags: xslt, try-catch, saxon

I am looking for a way to generate additional file with error message in case of processing failure.
For example replacement for function concat:

```
  <xsl:function name="my:concat">
    <xsl:param name="value1" as="node()*"/>
    <xsl:param name="value2" as="node()*"/>
    <xsl:try>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($value1,$value2)"/>
      <xsl:catch>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($value1[1],$value2[1])"/>
        <xsl:variable name="LOCALNAME_ERROR" as="xs:string" select="'error.xml'"/>
        <xsl:result-document href="{$LOCALNAME_ERROR}" method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no">
          <ERROR>
            <DOCID>
              <xsl:value-of select="'DOCID'"/>
            </DOCID>
            <ERRORCODE>
              <xsl:value-of select="$err:code"/>
            </ERRORCODE>
            <ERRORDESCRIPTION>
              <xsl:value-of select="$err:description"/>
            </ERRORDESCRIPTION>
            <FIELDNAME>
              <xsl:value-of select="if (count($value1) &gt; 1) then name($value1[1]) else name($value2[1])"/>
            </FIELDNAME>
            <FIELDPATH>
              <xsl:value-of select="if (count($value1) &gt; 1) then path($value1[1]) else path($value2[1])"/>
            </FIELDPATH>
            <FIELDVALUE>
              <xsl:value-of select="if (count($value1) &gt; 1) then $value1 else $value2"/>
            </FIELDVALUE>
          </ERROR>
        </xsl:result-document>
      </xsl:catch>
    </xsl:try>
  </xsl:function>
```

So in case of two occurrences it will produce a nice error message with info where error happened.

Test file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<DUMMY_001>
    <field1>value_1</field1>
    <field2>value_abc</field2>
    <field2>value_xyz</field2>
    <field3>value_3</field3>
    <field4>value_4</field4>
</DUMMY_001>
```

Outcome:

```
<ERROR>
   <DOCID/>
   <ERRORCODE>err:XPTY0004</ERRORCODE>
   <ERRORDESCRIPTION>A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of concat()</ERRORDESCRIPTION>
   <FIELDNAME>field2</FIELDNAME>
   <FIELDPATH>/Q{}DUMMY_001[1]/Q{}field2[1]</FIELDPATH>
   <FIELDVALUE>value_abc value_xyz</FIELDVALUE>
</ERROR>
```

In saxon 9.9.1.7 the error is: XTDE1480 Cannot execute xsl:result-document while evaluating xsl:function, but in saxon 9.6.0.7 it works.
Could you advise if there is a reliable way to create such error messages in the latest saxon versions?

Comment: I think the XSLT 3 spec disallows the use of `xsl:result-document` in an `xsl:function`; https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#result-document-restrictions. So you will have to restructure your code and perhaps call your function in an `xsl:try` and if it throws use `xsl:result-document` in `xsl:catch`.

Comment: The idea is to have try-catch inside the function and put it in the library, so we can reuse this library. The alternative is to put all the functions in try-catch for all the code written by developers which against DRY principle and will make the xslt code simply ugly.

Comment: As far as I understand the spec, you are not allowed to use `xsl:result-document` inside of `xsl:function`. So you will need to find a way to organise and structure your code without putting `xsl:result-document` into function code, as far as I understand it.